# How do I troubleshoot a 404 error on a webapp accessed via apache vhost?

Tags: rest, apache2, jetty, lift, vhosts

In my development system ( macos ) I have a webapp running in a jetty container on port 8080

Part of this webapp is a REST service

I can hit the REST service as follows

```
curl http://fake.hostname.com:8080/find/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nfl.com
```

and I get the expected JSON result from this call.

Because on the server I am deploying on, I have an apache front end using ajp to route to tomcat, on my dev system I have an apache vhost routing to port 8080. This helps with testing some oauth dependencies where facebook redirects to a specific host URL.

The webapp works fine in this configuration except when I try and hit the service using

```
curl http://fake.hostname.com/find/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nfl.com
```

Nothing is showing up in the jetty console reporting a proplem and I am getting a 404 response from apache.

Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot such an issue? Or things I should look at?

note 1. I know the issue of using apache as a proxy to tomcat or jetty is contentious but given there are other apps already living on apache port 80 I’m not willing to run tomcat in its place.

note 2. the webapp is in scala using the lift framework.

Comment: Can you try using http instead of ajp to forward your request? Also, if that doesn't help - can you post your apache conf file, curious as to the options used for forwarding. Also, do the error logs (global or for the virtual host) in a apache have any errors?

Comment: You mention tomcat and jetty both in your question.  which is it?

Comment: What if you curl directly to 8080?
You may want to try writeshark/tshark to monitor traffic between apache and 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the exact question, but did you consider to use `nginx` as a proxy+load balancer? It's a de-facto standard, as far as I know.

Also, what's in the logs? tomcat-s logs, apache logs..